# Component custom options in Nuxt with Vue 3 composition API

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3

In Vue 2, you can add custom options to a component definition object:

```
export default {
    title: 'TITLE',
    name: ...,
    components: { ... },
    render(h) { ... }
};
```

... and those options will appear in the component's `$options` property (`this.$options.title === 'TITLE'`).

Furthermore, with Webpack, you can add code that reads custom blocks in a single-file component and writes them to the component's `options` property.

I'm developing an application in Nuxt with the [module that implements the Vue 3 composition API for Nuxt](https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api). This is a brand-new application, so I'm just going directly to Vue 3 and the composition API. However, I'm at a dead stop on the matter of bringing in custom options. I have searched the results of both the `context` argument of the `setup` function and the Nuxt context provided by [useContext()](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/useContext) with no luck

How can I get the custom options from a component in Nuxt with the Vue 3 composition API module?

Comment: In which scenario would you need the custom options?

Comment: To read custom blocks and inject their content into the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getCurrentInstance()` to then access `$options`. Not sure if that's "Vue3-proof" though

This example will log "test" on the server-side:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default {
  setup() {
    console.log(getCurrentInstance().$options.test) // Logs 'Test'
  },
  test: 'Test'
}
```

You can use `onMounted` (or `onBeforeMount`) to access the value on client-side as well:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance, onMounted } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default {
  setup() {
    /* Logs 'Test' on mounted */
    onMounted(() => { console.log(getCurrentInstance().$options.test) })
  },
  test: 'Test'
}
```

Comment: @JayBienvenu feel free to check out my example CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-gareth-hyfp4?file=/pages/index.vue
It logs "test" as expected. I've also addded a "onMoutned" hook so it's logged on both, server & client side